# I want to find out the data for 1st of a month till 8th of a month. How do I do it using SQL

Tags: mysql

I want to find out the data for 1st of a month till 8th of a month. How do I do it using SQL

used extract function in where clause

```
EXTRACT(month FROM order_date) in (03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12) and EXTRACT(day FROM order_date) in (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08) and EXTRACT(year FROM order_date) = 2022
```

Comment: Correct, it works with an SQL query. However yours in the question looks incomplete. Check the [help] about the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: We need also more information about the table structure, particularly for the type of `order_date`

Comment: I want to find out the data for 1st of each month to 8th of each month.

Comment: order_date is datetime type.

Comment: What you have should work , what's your problem (apart from it being a bit ugly)?

Comment: Is there any other way than this. Can I use python to get this kind of period.

Comment: I going to take a guess that since you haven't included 01 and 02 in your published code what you mean by period is 2022-03 to 2023-02 inclusive?